# Looping through list of objects, when the objects values equal 50 do something with everything before and after 50

Tags: c#, list, loops, class, foreach

Sorry about the title can't thing of anything else that explains it!

So I have a list of hours that represent someones working hours.

Within those hours I workout how many hours have been worked before a certain time each day e.g. before 10:00pm and how many after.

My class properties are below.

I need to do loop through a list of these hours, and process them.

The tricky part is when you work over 50 hours then you get paid at different rates so everything under 50 at one rate and everything over 50 is at a higher rate.

So I need to loop through and figure out the exact point at which the total hours hit 50 and then know how many hours of that 50 were 'beforecutoff' and how many were 'aftercutoff'. Then do the same for the hours worked after 50.

The Hours prop below will be made up of (HoursBeforeCuttOff  + HoursAfterCutOff )

I cant think how to achieve this, any ideas would be welcome

```
public double Hours { get; set; }
public double HoursBeforeCuttOff { get; set; }
public double HoursAfterCutOff { get; set; }
```

Comment: it is very badly explained, and it looks like homework. can you add more code/logic you already have so we can **help** you to fix it. 
but having a quick look I can say you're missing a list of day-hour, or day-beforecutoff-aftercutoff

Comment: Yes will add code examples so far, what’s badly explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, that should work.

```
double hoursSum = 0;
double hoursSumBeforeCutoffUnder50 = 0;
double hoursSumAfterCutoffUnder50 = 0;
double hoursSumBeforeCutoffOver50 = 0;
double hoursSumAfterCutoffOver50 = 0;
foreach(var h in listOfHours)
{
  if(hoursSum >= 50)
  {
    // we're over 50, just add the hours before and after cutoff to the sums
    // hoursSum can be ignored from here on, it's no longer used.
    hoursSumBeforeCutoffOver50 += h.HoursBeforeCutoff;
    hoursSumAfterCutoffOver50 += h.HoursAfterCutoff;
  }
  else if(hoursSum + h.Hours > 50)
  {
    // this entry will pass the line of 50 hours. The hours are added depending of where the line is crossed
    if(hoursSum + h.HoursBeforeCutoff > 50)
    {
      hoursSumBeforeCutoffUnder50 += 50 - hoursSum;
      hoursSumBeforeCutoffOver50 += hoursSum + h.HoursBeforeCutoff - 50;
    }
    else { hoursSumBeforeCutoffOver50 += h.HoursBeforeCutoff; }

    hoursSum += h.HoursBeforeCutoff;

    if(hoursSum < 50)
    {
      hoursSumAfterCutoffUnder50 += 50 - hoursSum;
      hoursSumAfterCutoffOver50 += hoursSum + h.HoursAfterCutoff - 50;
    }
    else { hoursSumAfterCutoffOver50 += h.HoursAfterCutoff; }

    hoursSum += h.HoursAfterCutoff;
  }
  else{
    // the 50 hours are not yet reached, just add the hours
    hoursSum += h.Hours;
    hoursSumBeforeCutoffUnder50 += h.HoursBeforeCutoff;
    hoursSumAfterCutoffUnder50 += h.HoursAfterCutoff;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, will check it over ASAP and report back

Comment: Ive added it in and it certainly looks to be the right way to do it. I will be testing with data on saturday morning so will update, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
I'm writing the hours in the code, so this becomes pseudocode.
I'm assuming you always work in full hours and each entry in the list represents a full hour.

```
var hoursBeforeCutOff = listOfHours.Where(h => h < 10:00pm).Take(50).ToList();
var hoursAfterCutOff = listOfHours.Where(h => h < 10:00pm).Skip(50).ToList();
```

If you need something different, you should update the question accordingly, including your data model. A list of hours means something different in each domain. We cannot guess what your domain looks like.